# How to add JavaScript and JSX comments in the same .js file

Tags: comments, plugin-vim-commentary

I've been using Neovim to do the majority of my dev work for most of 2018 however something that has eluded me is being able to quickly toggle JSX comments

```
{/* JSX */}
```

and regular Javascript comments in the same `.js` file.

```
// single line JavaScript comment
```

Until last night I had been using [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) to quickly toggle / comment a line of source in whatever language I was working with using the below mapping

```
noremap <leader>c :Commentary<cr>
```

which works great for 99% of the languages I work with, however when I have to work with a JavaScript file that is a react based component and has JSX in it, `<leader>c` will place `//` when trying to comment a line of JSX within the render method.  I scanned through some of the issues of vim-commentary over at GitHub, and didn't really see a concrete example on how a single `.js` file could use `//` and `{/* JSX */}` within the same file using the same mapping.  However, I did come across this [issue](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary/issues/68) and didn't really see a solution presented within the issue thread.  One of the posters suggested [tcomment_vim](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim) which oddly enough has this open [issue](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim/issues/159) but once again the author of the plugin suggests [reading the source](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim/issues/159#issuecomment-175809947) of the plugin which references a [deprecated method](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim/blob/master/autoload/tcomment.vim#L200) in the plugin source.  Anyways, not really sure where to go from here ‍♂️, as always, any and all help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the following plugins:

- [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary)
- [vim-jsx](https://github.com/mxw/vim-jsx), to distinguish javascript and jsx files
- [vim-context-commentstring](https://github.com/suy/vim-context-commentstring), to change `commentstring` depending on the (syntax?) region.

Now, depending of the position within the file, either `//` or `{/* */}` style comments are used.

Update: Note that this sometimes tricky. Assume you have the following code:

```
const element = (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
  </div>
);
```

If the cursor is on the word Hello and you hit `gci)` to comment the inner part of the () you get

```
const element = (
  {/* <div> */}
  {/*   <h1>Hello!</h1> */}
  {/* </div> */}
);
```

If you would want the entire element commented you could hit `gca)`. You get:

```
{/* const element = ( */}
{/*   <div> */}
{/*     <h1>Hello!</h1> */}
{/*   </div> */}
{/* ); */}
```

If the cursor is on the opening bracket in the first line and you hit `gca)` you get:

```
// const element = (
//   <div>
//     <h1>Hello!</h1>
//   </div>
// );
```

Comment: wow Ralf, i'll totally give that a go here in a few, thanks for sharing. 

Comment: Any reason several vim configuration lines were removed from this answer in the past 24 hours?  As installing all three plugins alone is not enough of a solution to achieve the functionality I would like have.

Comment: @ipatch Removed as it works for me without the additional vimrc-cfg. The lines  are already contained in  vim-context-commentstring [here](https://github.com/suy/vim-context-commentstring/blob/ffcbd3b27c5e40a803426388148eec178f73d87b/autoload/context/commentstring.vim#L20-L26).

Comment: Ralf

just confirmed the steps above you describe do in fact distinguish between regular JS `//` comments and JSX `{/* */}` comments.

Comment: vim-jsx is now recommending to use https://github.com/MaxMEllon/vim-jsx-pretty and it worked as a perfect substitute. Thanks for this.

Comment: I'm already using `vim-commentary`. Adding the two other plugins (`vim-jsx-pretty` and `vim-context-commentstring`) had no effect -- I still get `//` style comments inside the JSX (or TSX). What other config might I be missing?

Comment: Related [vim-commentary issue](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary/issues/149).